# How to calculate current limiter resistors for ULN2803 and Relay?

Tags: microcontroller, relay, current-limiting, pullup, uln2803

I'm designing a digital I/O, and for the outputs I have ULN2803 and relays. I have the schematic below.

The coil current of relay is 16.7mA, ULN2803's max input current is 1.35mA and output current is 500mA/per channel used.

How should I calculate the current limiter resistors? My MCU works with 3.3V, driving the relays with 24V. What happens if a current flows more than 16.7mA to the relays?

And should I use pull-up or down resistors for input and outputs. I don't want any floating pin and activate the relay when I don't want.

[image]

[image]

[image]

THANK YOU!

Comment: If the relays are designed for 24V, then you don't need resistors.

Comment: Even pull-up or down res?

Comment: The ULN2803 has built in pull downs, so additional pull downs shouldn't be needed.

Comment: You don't need input or pull-down resistors and you don't even need the diodes (they are redundant with the COM connection to +24 - the ULN2803 has internal diodes for this exact purpose).

Answer (score 2):

The ULN2803 is a darlington transistor array, meaning it works basically just like a normal transistor - a current controlled **switch**.
This switch does not push current through the relay, it is merly closing the circuit "VCC-Relay-ULN-Ground".
You can also see this in the datasheet: the 500mA are an **absolute maximum rating**, not a characteristic that is simply always fulfilled.
Therefore, you do not need any current limiting resistors on the output side.

If you used a single transistor, you should use a current limiting resistor on its base, but this is handled by the ULN.

Concerning pullup/pulldown resistors: I would recommend to use a ~10k pulldown on the input side. Generally you don't need it, but it can prevent the relay from switching on when the uC is in reset state.

Comment: Did you mean the digital inputs? or Input side of the ULN (asking for pulldown res.)?

Comment: I meant the input side of the ULN, but as HandyHowie pointed out the ULN has internal pulldowns, so there is no need for additional ones.